# mysql join table with 2 fk to same table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, left-join

Table `join`:

```
|ID|admin|user |data|
|1 |00001|00002|XXXX|
```

- `admin`(fk) = `users.id`,
- `user`(fk) = `users.id`.

Table `users`:

```
|id   |name|pass|type |
|00001|root|1234|admin|
|00002|user|1235|user |

select join.*,users.name as admin,users.name as user from join 
left join users on users.id=join.admin
left join users on users.id=join.user

where grrrrrrr
```

How can I do this?

Original query, I'm trying to run:

```
SELECT

    visits.id,
    visits.patient AS patient_id,
    visits.doctor AS doctor_id,
    visits.date,
    visits.time_booked,
    visits.time_arrived,
    visits.time_start,
    visits.time_end,
    visits.type_id,
    visits.complain,
    visits.diagnosis,
    visits.note,
    visits.stats,
    (personal.name WHERE personal.id=visits.patient and personal.role='patient') AS pt_name,
    (personal.name WHERE personal.id=visits.doctor and personal.role='doctor') AS dr_name
    FROM
    visits ,
    personal
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to alias the table `users` with different aliases. Something like

```
select 
  a.*,
  u1.name as admin,
  u2.name as user 
from `join` a 
left join users u1 on u1.id = a.admin
left join users u2 on u2.id = a.`user`;
```

Also you have to escape the table name `join`, `user` since they are reserved keywords in MySQL. Try to avoid those names as object names.

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d1bcc/1)

This will give you:

```
| ID | ADMIN | USER | DATA |
----------------------------
|  1 |     1 |    2 | XXXX |
```

---

### Update

For your query after you updated your question, you have to do this the same way, like this:

```
SELECT
  v.id,
  v.patient AS patient_id,
  v.doctor AS doctor_id,
  v.date,
  v.time_booked,
  v.time_arrived,
  v.time_start,
  v.time_end,
  v.type_id,
  v.complain,
  v.diagnosis,
  v.note,
  v.stats,
  pationts.name AS pt_name,
  doctors.name AS dr_name
FROM visits v
LEFT JOIN personal pationts  ON pationts.id   = v.patient 
                            AND pationts.role ='patient'
LEFT JOIN personal doctors   ON doctors.id    = v.patient 
                            AND doctors.role  ='doctor';
```

### [Updated SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db7a5/2)